# How can I make Twitter Bootstrap Popover that always be open?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I want to make Twitter Bootstrap Popover that when document loaded, be open for ever. i see some solution but they show popover by `click` or `hover`!

There is my code:

```
$("#min-allowed-price .bar-label-shape").popover({
    offset: 10,
    trigger:'manual'
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to show popover manually and then remove the click event handler for the popover link.

```js
$('.popover-visible-trigger')
    .popover('show')
    .off('click');
```

See the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ejobu9q/1/).

The thing, though, is that maybe you don't need to do that. If you want the popover displayed at all times why not add it to markup?

Comment: Could you please more explain about it! what's markup? tnx

Comment: The thing is you can do that in a more efficient way without js. Bootstrap appends the popover block to the html, and this takes time to execute. So instead of relying on that, you can insert the popover code into your html yourself. See https://jsfiddle.net/5ejobu9q/2/, you can adjust the styling according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to make Twitter Bootstrap Popover that when document loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").popover("show");
});
```

> be open for ever.

Add `disabled` attribute to button or `preventDefault()` on `hide.bs.popover event`

```
$('button').on('hide.bs.popover', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxtjr39b/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually triggering the popover. You can do that by calling `popover('show')`:

```
$("#min-allowed-price .bar-label-shape").popover({
  offset: 10,
  trigger:'manual'
}).popover('show');
```

From Bootstrap's [Popover documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovershow):

> #### `.popover('show')`
>
> Reveals an element's popover. Returns to the caller before the popover has actually been shown (i.e. before the shown.bs.popover event occurs). This is considered a "manual" triggering of the popover. Popovers whose both title and content are zero-length are never displayed.
>
> ```
> $('#element').popover('show')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 example for keeping popover always visible:

- on click

```js
// initialize popovers
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]');
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => {
  // prevent hiding each popover
  popoverTriggerEl.addEventListener('hide.bs.popover', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger mt-5 ms-5" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

- right away (show automatically as soon as it's initiated)

```js
// initialize popovers
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]');
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => {
  // prevent hiding each popover
  popoverTriggerEl.addEventListener('hide.bs.popover', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  const popoverEl = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
  popoverEl.show();
  return popoverEl;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger mt-5 ms-5" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```